# How to adjust for lognormal distribution in linear regression when dependent variable is a ratio?

Tags: regression, distributions, lognormal-distribution, logarithm

I am working on a model that uses a dependent variable (Damage ratio) that is a ratio composed of two other variables (Flood damage / market value). One of those variables follows lognormal distribution (Flood damage), the other one follows a normal distribution (Market value). Together, the ratio also follows a lognormal distribution.

Importantly, the dataset has already excluded outliers from the market value.

If I want to apply logarithms to this dependent variable, how do I best go about it? Does it make sense to apply log() on only the lognormally distributed variable and just calculate the ratio as is? Or should I apply it on the ratio directly, which would indirectly mean I would also apply it on the normally distributed variable.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you want to take a logarithm?

Comment: What is the basis to assert that Market value has a normal distribution? Presumably market values cannot be negative, so an actual normal distribution would be excluded. Do you mean instead that you failed to reject normality? You would also fail to reject an infinite number of non-normal distributions, had you checked them.

Comment: What are you modeling and why? That should be at the forefront of the question; the possible use of logs would be secondary to that.